# Encoding in Android TextView

Tags: android, string, encoding, textview

I'm new in Android.
When using Json Parsing, I have a problem with display text(maybe cause by font, I don't know).
This is my Json return:

```
{"Response":[{"Id":829,"Name":"Tiền không đem lại hạnh phúc nhưng...","ShortDescription":"Một tỷ phú tâm sự với bạn,...
```

But when I parse in TextView in android, the "Name" become:

```
 "Tiá»�n khÃ´ng Ä‘em láº¡i háº¡nh phÃºc nhÆ°ng..."
```

This text is in Vietnamese.
How can I fix it?

Comment: "text/html; charset=UTF-8"  check json data on Log

Comment: I fixed it. My problem is UTF-8 charset. Thank all for your help.

Comment: @VanDang Please accept an answer or create your own answer so that this question gets closed :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I fixed it. My problem is UTF-8 charset.

```
String name = "";
try {
    name = new String(c.getString("NAME").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

String decodedName = Html.fromHtml(name).toString();
```

Comment: Just great, Saved lot of effort of extending and also other solutions did not do the job.

Answer (score 4):

Use a webView to display text like this:

```
myWebView.loadData(myHtmlString, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: You can also try using TextView with: Html.fromHtml("your chars")

Answer (score 0):

*The problem you are getting actually encoding.
So the json string you are getting from your response
need to add a proper encoding format. So just do like this.*

**Whlie posting a json use like this**

```
StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(Your_json_string, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

**While getting the json object use like this**

```
    if (statuscode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
```