# special chars read as �

Tags: android, encoding, android-studio, character-encoding

when trying to display text in a `textView` whit special chars like this **öäå** they appear like this ���. I display the text like this `tv.setText("åäö");`

As I understand it you can't encode a TextView, so how do I make sure it is read as utf-8?

Comment: Have you had a look at This question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951741/encoding-in-android-textview     ?

Comment: start by making sure your source code is utf-8

Comment: @Raphaël yes but i don't understand what the 'c' is in "c.getString("NAME")"

Comment: @njzk2 I think it is this to for even when I hard coded a webView whit "öäå" is didn't work. But I have already tried to change source code encoding..

Comment: the simplest way would be to put your string in the strings.xml file, which is always utf-8 encoded in android studio.

Comment: Set your IDE preferences to use UTF-8.

Comment: also, in android studio, go to `Preferences -> Editor -> File Encoding`, make sure IDE and Project are set to UTF-8

Comment: @njzk2 ... yes, exactly.

Comment: @njzk2 tried it twice now, even restarted ADB,Android studio and the running emulator. Not working.

Comment: @user2034253 Are you using getResources().getString(R.string.yourString); to get your string from a string.xml file ? As njzk2 said, that might also help...

Comment: @Raphaël when i do this it works grate, the problem is the files I'm read from is huge like 1000 rows whit statements and I want a random one. Getting a R.string.myString is a pain in the a** and putting in 1000 row is also a pain in the a**

Comment: Are you converting that said string in UTF-8 ? is the file you are reading from in utf-8 ? if not to any of those answers, you probably need to encode/convert your input/read into utf-8

Comment: @Raphaël yes I need to do this, not doing it now because tv.setText("åäö") should work fine?

Comment: May depend of a few factors that are going on on your environnement/ide/code/device... Why not do it explicitly ?